# Xamarin Forms: Return String from Android Activity

Tags: android, forms, xamarin

I'm trying to develop a mobile app in Xamarin Forms...One of the functionalities is text recognition. I need to recognize the text and then send it to another page (xaml). So i made an activity where it does recognize the text but i don't know how to return the string "Resultados" (Results). I tried to do a little search and many suggested that the "OnActivityResult" should return the values...but it doesnt get triggered.

Can anyone help me out what i am doing wrong?

TextRecognition.cs - activity(android)

```
public class TextRecognition : AppCompatActivity, ISurfaceHolderCallback, IProcessor, ITextRecognition
  {
      private SurfaceView cameraView;
      private TextView textView;
      private CameraSource cameraSource;
      public string Resultados;
      private const int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;

      protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
      {

          base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

          SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
          cameraView = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surface_view);
          textView = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtview);

          TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(ApplicationContext).Build();
          if (!textRecognizer.IsOperational)
          {
              Log.Error("Main Activity", "Detector dependencies are not yet available");
          }
          else
          {
              cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(ApplicationContext, textRecognizer)
                  .SetFacing(CameraFacing.Back)
                  .SetRequestedFps(2.0f)
                  .SetRequestedPreviewSize(1280, 1024)
                  .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                  .Build();

              cameraView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
              textRecognizer.SetProcessor(this);
          }

          Android.Widget.Button logonButton = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.button_send);
          logonButton.Click += delegate {
              button_OnClick();
          };
      }

      public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
      {
          switch (requestCode)
          {
              case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                  {
                      if (grantResults[0] == Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
                      {
                          cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
                      }
                  }
                  break;
          }
      }

      public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
      {

      }

      public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
      {
          if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
          {
              ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[]
              {
                  Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera
              }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
              return;
          }
          cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
      }

      public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
      {
          cameraSource.Stop();
      }

      public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
      {
          SparseArray items = detections.DetectedItems;
          if (items.Size() != 0)
          {
              textView.Post(() =>
              {
                  StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                  for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); i++)
                  {
                      strBuilder.Append(((TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i)).Value);
                      strBuilder.Append("\n");
                  }
                  textView.Text = strBuilder.ToString();
                  Resultados = strBuilder.ToString();
              });
          }
      }

      async void button_OnClick()
      {
          Toast.MakeText(this, "Hello from " + Resultados, ToastLength.Long).Show();
          Intent data = new Intent(this, typeof(TextRecognition));
          SetResult(Result.Ok, data);
          Finish();
      }

      public void Release()
      {

      }

      public string LaunchActivityInAndroid()
      {
          Activity activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
          var intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(TextRecognition));
          activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, Convert.ToInt32(Result.Ok));
          return Resultados;

      }

      protected override void OnActivityResult(int requestCode, Result resultCode, Intent data)
      {
          base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);


          switch(resultCode)
          {
              case Result.Ok:
                  break;
          }

          Finish();
      }



      public interface ITextRecognition
      {

      }


  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried to do a little search and many suggested that the "OnActivityResult" should return the values...but it doesnt get triggered.

You are using `OnActivityResult` a bit wrong. For example, if you have two Activity, `ActivityA` and `ActivityB`, `OnActivityResult` method in `ActivityA`, `ActivityB` need return some value to `ActivityA`, we can use `activityA.StartActivityForResult()` to open `ActivityB`,

`ActivityB` Use `SetResult` method to send data to `ActivityA`.

```
 public class ActivityB: Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.PutExtra("respond", "Hello,Alice!I'm Bob.");
            SetResult(Result.Ok, intent);

        }
    }
```

Then `OnActivityResult`will be triggered in the `ActivityA`.

> I need to recognize the text and then send it to another page (xaml)

If you want to send data from Activity to Forms pages, You can use `MessagingCenter` to achieve it.

`In Activity`, we can use following code to send it.

```
MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(App.Current as App, "OpenPage", "You send message:" + Resultados);
```

In the xamarin forms pages, you can use following code to get it.

```
MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(App.Current, "OpenPage", (snd, arg) =>
            {
                var getValue = arg;
            });
```

Here is a link about `MessagingCenter`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/messaging-center

===========**update**===========

I write a scan demo. Here is running gif.

[image]

Here is interface about dependenceService.

```
    public interface ITextRecognition
    {
        void LaunchActivityInAndroid();
    }
```

Here is achievement about dependenceService.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Graphics;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Support.V7.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using FormsTextRecognizer.Droid;

using Xamarin.Forms;
using static Android.Gms.Vision.Detector;
using Android.Gms.Vision;
using Android.Gms.Vision.Texts;
using Android.Support.V4.App;
using Android;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Util;

[assembly: Dependency(typeof(TextRecognition))]
namespace FormsTextRecognizer.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "ScanActivity", Theme = "@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar")]
    public class TextRecognition : AppCompatActivity, ITextRecognition,  ISurfaceHolderCallback, IProcessor
    {
        // private CameraSource cameraSource;
        private SurfaceView cameraView;
        TextRecognizer textRecognizer;
        private const int RequestCameraPermissionID = 1001;
        private CameraSource cameraSource;
        public string Resultados;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
            cameraView = FindViewById<SurfaceView>(Resource.Id.surface_view);
            Android.Widget.Button logonButton = FindViewById<Android.Widget.Button>(Resource.Id.button_send);
            textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context).Build();
        //    Android.Gms.Vision.Frame frame = new Android.Gms.Vision.Frame.Builder().SetBitmap(bitmap).Build();
            if (!textRecognizer.IsOperational)
            {
                Log.Error("Main Activity", "Detector dependancies are not yet available");
            }
            else
            {
                cameraSource = new CameraSource.Builder(ApplicationContext, textRecognizer)
                    .SetFacing(CameraFacing.Back)
                    .SetRequestedFps(2.0f)
                    .SetRequestedPreviewSize(1920, 1080)
                    .SetAutoFocusEnabled(true)
                    .Build();

                cameraView.Holder.AddCallback(this);
                textRecognizer.SetProcessor(this);
            }


            logonButton.Click += LogonButton_Click;
        }

        private void LogonButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // throw new NotImplementedException();
            Toast.MakeText(this, Resultados, ToastLength.Short).Show();

            MessagingCenter.Send<App, string>(App.Current as App, "OpenPage", "You send message:" + Resultados);


            Finish();
        }

        public void LaunchActivityInAndroid()
        {
            //string ScanText = "";
            Activity activity = Forms.Context as Activity;
            var intent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(TextRecognition));
            activity.StartActivity(intent);
           // activity.StartActivityForResult(intent, Convert.ToInt32(Result.Ok));
          //  return Resultados;

        }

        public void ReceiveDetections(Detections detections)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();
            SparseArray items = detections.DetectedItems;
            if (items.Size() != 0)
            {

                    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < items.Size(); i++)
                    {
                        strBuilder.Append(((TextBlock)items.ValueAt(i)).Value);
                        strBuilder.Append("\n");
                    }
              //      textView.Text = strBuilder.ToString();
                    Resultados = strBuilder.ToString();
               // });
            }
        }

        public void Release()
        {
          //  throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public void SurfaceChanged(ISurfaceHolder holder, [GeneratedEnum] Format format, int width, int height)
        {

        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            switch (requestCode)
            {
                case RequestCameraPermissionID:
                    {
                        if (grantResults[0] == Permission.Granted)
                        {
                            cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
                        }
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        public void SurfaceCreated(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            //throw new NotImplementedException();

            if (ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(ApplicationContext, Manifest.Permission.Camera) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted)
            {
                //Request Permission
                ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(this, new string[] {
                    Android.Manifest.Permission.Camera
                }, RequestCameraPermissionID);
                return;
            }
            cameraSource.Start(cameraView.Holder);
        }

        public void SurfaceDestroyed(ISurfaceHolder holder)
        {
            cameraSource.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is Forms page background code.

```
    [DesignTimeVisible(false)]
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


            MessagingCenter.Subscribe<App, string>(App.Current, "OpenPage", (snd, arg) =>
            {
                scanLabel.Text = arg;
            });
        }

        private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           DependencyService.Get<ITextRecognition>().LaunchActivityInAndroid();
        }
    }
```

Here is my demo, you can refer to it.

https://github.com/851265601/FormsTextRecognizer

Comment: I'm a little bit confused...

In my xamarin forms page i initialize the activity by doing this:

`code`
        public void SelectedCamera(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<ITextRecognition>();
             string g =  DependencyService.Get<ITextRecognition>().LaunchActivityInAndroid();
            
        }


        public interface ITextRecognition
        {
            string LaunchActivityInAndroid();
        }

Comment: and in my Activity i ended by doing this:

`code`
        async void button_OnClick()
        {
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Hello from " + Resultados, ToastLength.Long).Show();
            Intent data = new Intent(this, typeof(TextRecognition));
            SetResult(Result.Ok, data);
            MessagingCenter.Send((DiabetesAPP.App)Xamarin.Forms.Application.Current, "OpenPage", "You send message:" + Resultados);

            Finish();
        }


My question is where do i subscribe the message in my forms page?

Comment: @JoãoGodinho Please see my updated answer. If the reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click the “✔” in the left upper corner), it will help others who have similar issue.

Comment: Thanks man! It worked! Thank u so much for your patience and help :D